# Codeigniter: File not found

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

Why do the paths to my css,js and img files have the CONTROLLER name BEFORE 'application'?

Path from firebug:

localhost/quote-generator/**admin**/application/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css

My code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>" >
```

This is from a header.php file i have included in one of my views generated in my Admin controller in the 'login' function.

Any suggestions??

Comment: What is $config['base_url'] set to in your config.php file?

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'application/';

Comment: Should be set to the domain of your application. For example if your site was http://example.com then you would want to set $config['base_url'] = 'example.com'. You could also move your assets directory outside of your application directory so they are both in the same directory as your index.php file then instead of using base_url you could just simply reference '/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'

Comment: I tried that but the problem remains, the problem only occurs when accessing the login function of the admin controller, so /admin/login. It also occurs when simply entering http://localhost/quote-generator/admin/login/, with the / at the end, but without the '/' at the end, it simply goes to the index() function in the admin controller and the assets are loaded correctly. Strange

Comment: are you using any `.htaccess`?

Comment: Yes I am. I am using mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its bad practise to keep assets files, i.e. css/images in the application folder

Your Codeigniter folder structure should be this

```
root
  |
  |_______________application
  |_______________assets
                   |_________css
                   |_________images
```

considering the root is the admin

setting the above structure, set the base_url like this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/quote-generator/admin/';
```

then put the `href` like this

```
href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

Comment: 'Admin' is the name of one of my controllers. For some reason codeigniter is inserting the Controller name between the project directory and application, like this....: localhost/quote-generator/admin/application/assets/ Thus making the path broken. This only happens when accessing the admin controller, but not the index function of this controller. Super weird.

Answer (score -1):

use :

```
site_url()
```

instead of

```
base_url
```

it's saver that way